# popupcontrolextender web service 500 error

Tags: c#, popupcontrolextender

A user of my web applications is getting a web service 500 error, when using the popup extender control. However this is intermitent, I cannot reproduce this issue when debugging locally. I cannot think of anything that would cause this. I am looking for any potential issues that may cause this. Any suggestion would help at this point.

Below is the call to the popup extender control declaration.

```
 <cc1:PopupControlExtender ID="CSPopup" runat="server" TargetControlID="CSTextBox" PopupControlID="CSPanel" Position="Bottom" BehaviorID="pceCS" DynamicServiceMethod="GetXYSelections" DynamicServicePath="TSelector_WS.asmx" DynamicContextKey="NaN,0," DynamicControlID="CSPanel" />
```